# Why do I get "esc is not a function" on a commented-out line of code?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

When running this:

```
<header>
  <!--<% include ./employee/partials/emp-nav.ejs %>-->
  <% include ../partials/header.ejs %>
</header>
```

I get this error message:

```
TypeError: C:\Users\scttc\arcane-forest-29693\views\pages\example.ejs:43
    41|   <section class="hero" id="hero">

    42|     <header>

 >> 43|     <!--  <% include ./employee/partials/emp-nav.ejs %>-->

    44|       <% include ../partials/header.ejs %>

    45|     </header>

    46| 

esc is not a function
```

How am I getting an error on a commented-out line of code? This makes no sense to me.

Comment: perhaps whatever is pre-processing your code doesn't honour HTML comments - I see no `esc` on line 43 either, so ...

Comment: Try the [ejs](https://github.com/mde/ejs) comment tag `<%#` instead

Comment: M. Sallam: I tried that comment tag, but I got this error message: Error: Could not find matching close tag for "<%".